# Mysql date datatypes having (err) value

Tags: mysql

i have a data (MYSQL) with datatypes of date.
And it's having a value like this (err).
How do i fix this data? i wanted to select all the data with that (err), how to do that? because i tried to select it with

`SELECT * FROM MYTABLE where MYDATE IS NULL`

then it's not appearing, when i tried

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYDATE IS NOT NULL
```

yes it appear but also with the others recod.
and also tried

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYDATE ='(err)'
```

returns 0 record

this is the screenshot of the data

[image: myimage]

Comment: Might be a client thing, that it displays "(err)" for certain values (maybe for `'0000-00-00'`?)? What client are you using?

Comment: Oh okay, i used Aqua Data Studio and tried in DBeaver it got two null values eventhough I do distinct on it. And my Pentaho gave me an error it said that "zero date value prohibited"

Comment: because it seem that i can't seem to select the record that is having that weird values? i tried to do not between 01010001 and 12319999, 0 records returns